# MIKMIDI NRPN command creation

Tags: ios, objective-c, midi, mikmidi

I using MIKMIDI to send a combined NRPN command. I am trying to send a NRPN of this style

`B9H 63H 40H || B9H 62H 64H || B9H 06H 7FH (hex)`

which is

`B9 99 64 || B9 98 100 || B9 06 127 (dec)`

Which i try to create this way

```
// create the MSB and LSB command
MIKMutableMIDIControlChangeCommand *msb = [[MIKMutableMIDIControlChangeCommand alloc] init];
msb.channel          = 9;
msb.controllerNumber = 99;
msb.controllerValue  = 64;
MIKMutableMIDIControlChangeCommand *lsb = [[MIKMutableMIDIControlChangeCommand alloc] init];
lsb.channel          = 9;
lsb.controllerNumber = 98;
lsb.controllerValue  = 100;
// compose the full command
cmd = [MIKMutableMIDIControlChangeCommand commandByCoalescingMSBCommand:msb andLSBCommand:lsb];
cmd.channel          = 9;
cmd.controllerNumber = 6;
cmd.controllerValue  = 127;
```

But it returns a nil pointer.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The [`commandByCoalescingMSBCommand` documentation](https://github.com/mixedinkey-opensource/MIKMIDI/blob/master/Source/MIKMIDIControlChangeCommand.h#L29) says:

> This method is used internally by MIKMIDI, to coalesce incoming 14-bit control change commands.
>   it is not generally useful to external users of MIKMIDI. If you're simply trying to create a new
>   `MIKMIDIControlChangeCommand` instance, you should use plain `alloc`/`init` instead.

Comment: yep. i read that. but i thought i can do NRPNs with this command. Okay, will do all 3 commands separately. thanks